# Combine multiple data in .vue component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a country.vue component.

I'm doing a loop for. And in this loop, I'd like to collect only the country names based on the locale of the application.

To collect the locale, I create a new data called "local". I would like to combine this locale in my :label.

```
<template>
<li>
    <el-option
        v-for="country in countries"
        :key="country.name"
        :value="country.name"
        :label="country.translations.fr">
    </el-option>
</li>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            countries: [],
            locale: document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('lang')
                }
            },
             …
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
<el-option
    v-for="country in countries"
    :key="country.name"
    :value="country.name"
    :label="country.translations. ' + "locale" . ">
</el-option>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try `country.translations[locale]`?

Comment: @mhodges I did not know, but it works! It has a name? Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Just posted an answer with a link to more details. Glad that worked for you `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's built-in [Bracket Notation Property Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to accomplish this, like so:

```
<el-option
    v-for="country in countries"
    :key="country.name"
    :value="country.name"
    :label="country.translations[locale]">
</el-option>
```